# Google cloud load balancer redirect www to naked domain

Tags: dns, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, kubernetes-ingress

I'm using Google Cloud Load Balancer as the ingress controller to my GCP Kubernetes application.  I want all requests to `www.my_domain.com` to be redirected to `my_domain_.com`.

Note: My GCLB is configured with an SSL certificate that is valid for both `www.my_domain.com` and `my_domain.com`.

I know this is possible using an http redirect in my external DNS management console, but an issue arises because of SSL termination.

1. I create an http redirect rule in my DNS management console to route all `www.my_domain.com` traffic to `https://my_domain.com`.
2. If a client browses to domain `https://www.my_domain.com`, they will get a browser warning because the request will first go to server of my DNS management tool, which is not configured with a matching SSL cert.

I know that GCLB has limitations for redirecting http traffic to https, but that's not my main concern here.  What I want to know is if it's possible in GCLB to configure a routing rule so that any request for `www.my_domain.com` is redirected to `my_domain.com`.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Have you found a solution for GCLB Ingress?

Comment: @mikolaj not for GCLB ingress. i just used ingress nginx which is better overall: https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx

Comment: I did the same, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Redirect rules are supported when you switch your "Host and path rules" from the "Simple host and path rule" to the "Advanced host and path rule" option now. This advanced option allows for URL redirect and URL rewrite.

Edit your Load Balancer, go to "Host and path rules", click "Add host and path rule".

Host: `www.my_domain.com`

Path: `/*`

Action: `Redirect the client to different host/path` and specify your host `my_domain.com`

Path redirect: `Full path redirect`

Redirect response code: `301`

HTTPS redirect: `Enable`

Check this Google Cloud page (no screenshots unfortunately) here https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setting-up-url-redirects-classic

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no such functionality in GCLB.

In this case, you should use custom (for example **nginx**) ingress controller.

You can find **[here](https://hackernoon.com/setting-up-nginx-ingress-on-kubernetes-2b733d8d2f45)** and **[here](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/)** how to setup nginx controller for Kubernetes.