# Redirect www to non-www with GCP and Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, next.js, google-compute-engine, kubernetes-ingress

I am trying to redirect traffic from 'www' to 'non-www.'
If I apply advanced rules for the path and host in the Load Balancer in the GCP platform, it will redirect from 'www' to 'non-www.' However, it may take 3 to 5 minutes for the changes to update through the Ingress in Kubernetes. after updating ingress rule it will convert into simple rules not stick to the advanced rules.
I want to redirect all traffic from 'www' to 'non-www' permenent using an Ingress file. Can anyone suggest any solution?
Remember i am using gce class in ingress and use Dockerfile for kubernetes and GCP.

I am attaching this 'ingress.yml' file for reference.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: alb-ingress
  namespace: production
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "gce"
    networking.gke.io/managed-certificates: gke-managed-cert
    networking.gke.io/v1beta1.FrontendConfig: ssl-redirect
spec:
  rules:
  - host: marutitech.com
    http:
      paths:
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: /
        backend:
          service:
            name: maruti-nextjs
            port:
              number: 80
  - host: www.marutitech.com
    http:
      paths:
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: /
        backend:
          service:
            name: maruti-nextjs
            port:
              number: 80
```

[Google cloud load balancer redirect www to naked domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52141212/google-cloud-load-balancer-redirect-www-to-naked-domain)
take this as refrence.